# D&D 5e Can Wish change the composition of Simulacrum?

Tags: dnd-5e, wish, simulacrum

Simulacrum is made of ice, right?

So, would it be possible to turn that ice into mithril or adamantine with a wish spell?

If possible, will this Simulacrum be able to behave normally like a golem?

If you can get additional abilities as well, how much is reasonable?

Comment: Welcome to the stack, take the [tour] when you have a moment. We have gotten lots of questions about *wish* before, about what it can do, what are its limits, etc., and they all generally have exactly the same answer - it’s up to the DM. I’ve closed this as a duplicate of one of those questions where I provided detailed guidance for players and DMs to get the most out of the *wish* spell at the table of play.